# If $m_1 \mid c, \, \dots, \, m_n \mid c$, then $[m_1, \, \dots, m_n] \mid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove that if $m_1 \mid c, \, \dots, \, m_n \mid c$, then $[m_1, \, \dots, m_n] \mid c$. Here $[ \cdot ]$ is the LCM function. I know that each of the $m_i \mid [m_1, \, \dots, m_n]$ by definition but haven't gotten much further than that.

Comment: That is the characterisation of the least common multiple!  What definition do you use?

Comment: @Bernard $[\cdot]$ is the least positive integer such that all of the arguments divide $[\cdot]$.

Comment: It is also the least for the relation of divisibility.

Comment: Isn't that a definition of lcm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that if $|c|\le [m_1,\dots,m_n]$ then $|c|=[m_1,\dots,m_n]$ since $[m_1,\dots,m_n]$ is the least positive integer with the property given $c$.

Now use the division algorithm to write

$$c=k[m_1,\dots,m_n]+r$$

where $k$ is an integer and $0\le r<[m_1,\dots,m_n]$. Since $m_i\mid c$, we have 
$$m_i\mid k[m_1,\dots,m_n]+r\hspace{5mm}\implies\hspace{5mm}m_i\mid r$$

So $i=1,2,\dots,n$ we have $m_i|r$. If $r$ is positive, by definition, $r\ge[m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n]$ which does not fall within our bound $0\le r<[m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n]$. Hence $r=0$ and $[m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n]\mid c$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the prime decomposition of $c = \prod p_i^{a_i}$. Only these primes $\{p_i\}$ possibly divide the $\{m_j\}$, no others , and in each case the multiplicity of each $p_i$ in $m_j$ must be less than or equal to $a_i$. So it's also true that only primes from $\{p_i\}$ divide lcm$[\{m_j\}]$ and in each case with multiplicity not greater than $a_i$.

Hence lcm$[m_1, m_2, ...m_n] \mid c$